# automatic line-break of textarea inside a form possible with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I know about the nl2br function... But is there a way to set a maximum length of a line?
Im using php to get results from a form, which contains a textarea.
I dont want words to get broken to newlines, like the word 'example' to become 'exa
mple'

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap) to force a line break:

```
wordwrap($str, 123, "<br>\n", true)
```

Comment: anyway to wrap before php, just with html? I dont want the text to be weird, like break in the middle of a word...

Comment: @camran: The fourth parameter is for the hard cut after the exact number of given bytes.

Comment: textarea has `cols` but that's not a new line, just a presentation wrap.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function in php.